# Angular application requires to select language to show translation

Tags: angular, internationalization, firebase-hosting

I have trouble with deploying an Angular Web Application that has internationalization for two languages. Locally, everything works fine, but when I deploy the application to Firebase, it either does not show any text or shows the keys from the i18n JSON configuration unless a language is explicitly selected by a button click.

Below is my `app.module.ts` file:

```js
// Imports...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ProjectsComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    FooterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CdkAccordionModule,

    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

And here is my `app.component.ts`:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    // Set the default language to English
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }
}
```

The Angular application is being built into a `dist` directory with an `assets` folder and a subsequent folder present. As the reader can see, I tried to use the approach from React i18n - setting the default language value to `'en'` - but without a positive result.

How can I address this issue? I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: do you see the translation filedownloaded in the network tab?

Comment: No, and the console logs contain error messages that the GET failed with the following: `assets/i18n/null.json`. I presume that the null should be en, but I don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: try setting the default language `TranslateModule.forRoot({ defaultLanguage: ''en', ...`

Comment: Did not help. I think that I may have some missing configuration in the i18n library to include the assets subfolder

Comment: no, that should be fine. after you click something language gets downloaded correctly. your problem is most likely that somewhere in the application some code sets language to `null`

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding this to your app.component.ts

```
    this.translateService.setTranslation("it", it, true);
```

changing 'it' with the desired language. In this way you'll load the language you need.

The second param of the function should be an object, in my case I imported the whole file in this way:

```
import * as it from "../app/i18n/it.json";
```

Hope it helps!